# Can not figure out why navigation bar isn't working

Tags: css, navigation

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        </div>          
            <div id="nav">
                <ul id="navigation">
                    <li id="nav_home">Home</li>
                    <li id="nav_gallery">Gallery</li>
                    <li id="nav_shows">Shows</li>
                    <li id="nav_contact us">Contact us</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
        <div id="background">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Css :

```
#nav{
text-align: right;
margin-top: none;
```

}

```
#navigation{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 10px;
font-size: 17px;
font-family: monospace;
float: right;
position: relative;
```

}

I can not figure out why it is not working. When I try closing the `div` header tag after the list (bar) it appears above the logo image. And it is currently like this:

[image]

**EDIT: How to specify a style for this exact line? I tried anything but i couldn't, due to the fact that with DIV it gets under the whole Anime of the week -** http://gyazo.com/5c9c6b57cd7097edc719b09a8bbfdd1d

Answer (score 0):

Try this and then arrange the padding as per required :-

```
#navcontainer ul
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

#navcontainer ul li { display: inline; }

#navcontainer ul li a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: .2em 1em;
}



<div id="navcontainer">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cheese</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: http://gyazo.com/bfe7b7767ba26c39995e2661ae260e43 It's now like that with a margin: top / right

Comment: where exactly do you want this menu to be?

Answer (score 0):

Make necessary changes to replicate the block of CSS code below:

```
  #nav {
       margin-top: none;
       width: 500px; /* Define a width for the parent cont*/
    }

  #navigation {
      width: 100%; /* Adjsut as needed */
    }


 #navigation li {
   display: inline-block; 
   list-style: none;
   padding: 15px;
   }
```

[See working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/eeLe3610/1/)

**Important:** If the logo and the nav are both inside one container, find out what's left of the container after the width of the logo and use it as the with of the nav.

Comment: Now it is placed in the container 2 ( background image after the header ) http://gyazo.com/eaa072e366b6dc8ca8d4566b23ec71cc

Comment: I must not understand you question. Try making some adjustments.

Comment: Now i closed the tag for header after the list and it is on the right spot . Thank you ! P.S how to use a decent font?

Comment: Why can't I add the bottom images ? it doesn't even show them 
http://gyazo.com/fbd1fb7f56cb40db5e5951edcc7bc778

Comment: Can you tell me your skype in order to add you? Will be easier , thanks

Comment: can you tell me why my second part ( Best anime and etc. do not appear on the page?